# Prove the integral of $f(z)=\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{4z^2}$ tends to $0$ on the curve $\gamma=Re^{it}$ as $R\rightarrow{\infty}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am asked to prove that the integral of $f(z)=\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{4z^2}$ on the curve $\gamma=Re^{it}$ $0\leq t \leq \pi$, when $R\rightarrow{\infty}$, goes to zero. To do so I tried $$\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_0^{\pi}f(\gamma)\gamma'dt=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1-e^{2iRe^{it}}}{4(Re^{it})^2}Rie^{it}dt=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1-e^{2iRe^{it}}}{4R^2e^{it}}idt$$
And now I need to see that $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1-e^{2iRe^{it}}}{4R^2e^{it}}idt=0$$
However I don't know how to solve that integral so I can't proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the denominator should be $4Re^{it}.$ It's actually not too hard to see that the magnitude of the integrand $$i\frac{1-e^{2iRe^{it}}}{4Re^{it}}$$ is bounded by a multiple of $1/R$. Indeed, first note that $$|e^{2iRe^{it}}|=|e^{2iR(\cos t+i\sin t)}|=e^{-2R\sin t}\leq 1,$$ for $t\in [0,\pi],$ and so
$$\left|i\frac{1-e^{2iRe^{it}}}{4Re^{it}}\right|\leq\frac{1}{4R}+\frac{e^{-2R\sin t}}{4R}\leq\frac{1}{2R},$$ for $t\in [0,\pi].$ Using this to bound the integrand uniformly, $$\left|\int\limits_0^\pi i\frac{1-e^{2iRe^{it}}}{4Re^{it}}\ dt\right|\leq\frac{\pi}{2R}\rightarrow 0$$ as $R\rightarrow\infty.$

Comment: what about $\pi < t < 2\pi$? the inequality doesn't work.

Comment: That's not the region that they're integrating over; they specifically chose to integrate over growing half circles in the upper half plane.

Comment: my bad, I missed the domain of t

Comment: No problem; it happens to all of us!

Comment: Thank you for your anwer, could you elaborate on why the inequality would not work for $\pi<t<2\pi$?

Comment: Sure. In that scenario, $\sin t$ would be between $0$ and $-1,$ and so the exponential would be strictly positive near $3\pi/2$, leading to blowup as $R\rightarrow\infty.$

Comment: Correction (since I can’t edit the comment): the bound by 1 wouldn’t apply (blowup isn’t guaranteed).

Comment: In fact, the portion from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ is the only contribution to the integral as $R\rightarrow\infty.$ As shown in the linked post, the integral equals $\pi.$