# Prove $\lim_{r\to0}\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{1-e^{2ire^{it}}}{4r^2e^{it}}idt=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am trying to prove that
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}
\frac{1 - \exp\left(2\mathrm{i}r\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}\right)}{4r^{2}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}}\,\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{d}t =
\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Since I don't know how to solve the integral explicitly, I don't know what to do. This problem is really similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3230947/prove-the-integral-of-fz-frac1-e2iz4z2-tends-to-0-on-the-curve), maybe that answer is useful for this problem too.

Thank you.

Comment: Is $r$ going to $0$ or to $\infty$?

Comment: $\displaystyle\to \infty$ as $\displaystyle r \to 0^{+}$. However, $\displaystyle\to 0$ as $\displaystyle r \to \infty$. From $\texttt{Mathematica}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are integrating $\int_C f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z$ for $f(z)=(1-e^{2iz})/z^2$ with the parametrization $\require{color}C\colon z=re^{it}$, you forgot an $r$ in $\mathrm{d}z={\color{red}r}ie^{it}\,\mathrm{d}t$.

For $0<2r<1$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $\lvert 2ire^{it}\rvert=2r<1$ and hence
$$
\frac{1-e^{2ire^{it}}}{4r^2e^{it}}=\frac{1-(1+2ire^{it}+o(r))}{4r^2e^{it}}=\frac{-2ire^{it}+o(r)}{4r^2e^{it}}=-\frac{i}{2r}+o(r^{-1})
$$
Now integrate,
$$
\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{1-e^{2ire^{it}}}{4r^2e^{it}}{\color{red}r}i\,\mathrm{d}t=
\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\left[-\frac{i}{2r}+o(r^{-1})\right]{\color{red}r}i\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac\pi2+\underbrace{o(1)}_{\to 0}.
$$

Comment: Why for $0<2r<1$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lvert 2ire^{it}\rvert=2r<1$? Also, I don't understand this equality: $\frac{1-e^{2ire^{it}}}{4r^2e^{it}}=\frac{1-(1+2ire^{it}+o(r))}{4r^2e^{it}}$. Thank you for your answer and sorry for asking so many questions

Comment: We have $\lvert i\rvert=1$, and $\lvert e^{it}\rvert=1$, (because $t\in\mathbb{R}$) and so $\lvert 2ire^{it}\rvert=2r$.  Expanding exp to first order with remainder term $\exp(\zeta)=1+\zeta+o(\lvert\zeta\rvert)$ and substitute $\zeta=2ire^{it}$ gives $1-e^{2ire^{it}}=1-(1+2ire^{it}+o(r))$ that you see in the numerator.

Comment: Thank you again! Finally, in the last equality, when you integrate $(ir)(o(r^{-1}))=(i)(o(1))$, right? where did the $i$ go?

Comment: It goes into the $o(1)$, because $i$ is just a constant.

Comment: Also, what was your motivation to expanding exp to the first order? I would have never thought that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem that you linked discussed the limit as $r\rightarrow \infty,$ I'll say something about that, in case that is what you mean. I'll make the same assumption that the other response did regarding your definition of the function.

Call the integrate $f(z)=\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{4z^2}.$ Note that it has a simple pole at $z=0$. Then, calculating the residue at $z=0$ gives $Res_{z=0}(f)=-\frac{i}{2}.$ Applying the residue theorem to the disk $D_r(0)$, we have that $$\int\limits_{\partial D_r(0)}\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{4z^2}dz=2\pi i\left(\frac{-i}{2}\right)=\pi.$$ Note that $$\int\limits_{\partial D_r(0)}\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{4z^2}dz=\int\limits_{\Gamma_1}\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{4z^2}dz+\int\limits_{\Gamma_2}\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{4z^2}dz,$$ where $\Gamma_1$ is the contour in the linked problem and $\Gamma_2$ is your contour. Taking the limit as $r\rightarrow\infty,$ the integral along $\Gamma_1$ vanishes, yielding that your integral is equal to $\pi.$